# Creating and accessing the values of the record by matching the keys in erlang

Tags: erlang

I am trying to declaring and initializing the record with map **`(Example: -record(month_names,#{1=> "January",2=>"February",3=>"March",4=>"April",5=>"May",6=>"June",7=>"July",8=>"August",9=>"September",10=>"October",11=>"November",12=>"December"}).`**), but while i am trying to access the value of map its not getting the output.

Tried Code:

**

```
-module(main).
-export([calender/1]).
-record(month_days, #{1=> "31",2 => "28",3=>"31",4=>"30",5=>"31",6=>"30",7=>"31",8=>"31",9=>"30",10=>"31",11=>"30",12=>"31"}).
-record(month_names,#{1=> "January",2 => "February",3=>"March",4=>"April",5=>"May",6=>"June",7=>"July",8=>"August",9=>"September",10=>"October",11=>"November",12=>"December"}).
calender(Year) ->
 Day = #month_days{month_days= 1,val= 1},
 io:fwrite("~p~n",Year),
 io:fwrite("~p~n", [Day#month_days.month_days]).
```

**

But I am getting the error in the given below :

Error :

**

```
10> c(main).
main.erl:3: bad record declaration
main.erl:4: bad record declaration
main.erl:8: record month_days undefined
main.erl:10: record month_days undefined
error
```

**

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to declaring and initializing the record with map

That's not possible in Erlang. Erlang records have atoms as keys, optionally with default values provided, and cannot be initialised with maps. See the [programming examples for records](http://erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/records.html).

In this case, you don't need to use records; you can just use the maps as they are:

```
calender(Year) ->
 MonthDays = #{1=> "31",2 => "28",3=>"31",4=>"30",5=>"31",6=>"30",7=>"31",8=>"31",9=>"30",10=>"31",11=>"30",12=>"31"},
 MonthNames = #{1=> "January",2 => "February",3=>"March",4=>"April",5=>"May",6=>"June",7=>"July",8=>"August",9=>"September",10=>"October",11=>"November",12=>"December"},
 %% get number of days for month 1
 #{1 := Days} = MonthDays,
 io:fwrite("~p~n", [Year]),
 io:fwrite("~p~n", [Days]).
```

If you're mapping a small sequence of consecutive integers starting at 1, you can use a tuple instead of a map and access the corresponding value with the `element` function:

```
> MonthNames = {jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec}.
{jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec}
> MonthNumber = 2.
2
> element(MonthNumber, MonthNames).
feb
```

---

There are some library functions you might find useful, e.g. [`calendar:last_day_of_the_month/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/calendar.html#last_day_of_the_month-2) and [`calendar:day_of_the_week/3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/calendar.html#day_of_the_week-3):

```
> calendar:last_day_of_the_month(2020, 2).
29
> calendar:day_of_the_week(2021, 2, 17).
3
```

Answer (score 1):

A `record` is a shortcut for a tuple and not a map. The way to define the record is

```
-record(rec_name, {field1, field2 = 'default_value'}}.
```

Based on your code, `record` may not be an appropriate solution. You can just use a map.